# Indent text to beginning of line

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

Sometimes I'll have some text with an arbitrary indentation.

```
                Sample text.
```

If I want to bring this text back to the beginning of the line, I'll visually select the line and then indent a large number of times. So I type `V5<`

```
Sample text.
```

Is there a better way to bring the indentation back to the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:left`

From `:h left`:

```
:[range]le[ft] [indent]
            Left-align lines in [range].  Sets the indent in the
            lines to [indent] (default 0).
            Not available when |+ex_extra| feature was disabled at
            compile time.
```

You can also use `:h center` and `:h right` to align the current line to center and right.